# How can I set maximum width to which QScrollArea (within QDialog) will expand without adding scrollbar?

Tags: qt, qdialog, qscrollarea

I have `QDialog` and `QScrollArea` inside. When content in `QScrollArea` is small, dialog window is also small. When content width is increasing, dialog window's width is also encreasing but only to some fixed value.

When `QPushButton`'s width in my example is about 450 or more, vertical scrollbar appears. How can I avoid this and let dialog window expand more?

```
class Dialog : public QDialog {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Dialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QDialog(parent) {
    auto dialogLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);

    auto scrollArea = new QScrollArea(this);
    scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);
    auto scrollWidget = new QWidget(scrollArea);
    auto scrollLayout = new QVBoxLayout(scrollWidget);
    scrollLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop);
    scrollArea->setWidget(scrollWidget);

    dialogLayout->addWidget(scrollArea);

    auto button = new QPushButton("Button", this);
    button->setFixedSize(500, 30);

    scrollLayout->addWidget(button);
  }
};

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QMainWindow(parent)
  {
    auto centralWidget = new QWidget(this);
    setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
    auto mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout(centralWidget);

    auto button = new QPushButton("Dialog", this);
    mainLayout->addWidget(button);

    connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, []() {Dialog().exec();});
  }
};
```

I tried `QDialog::setMaximumWidth`, and setting Expanding size policy for both `QDialog` and `QScrollArea` but nothing helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QScrollArea constrains the maximum size of its `sizeHint()` method (comes out to 468px on my current Win7 machine). You can [see that here](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qscrollarea.cpp.html#_ZNK11QScrollArea8sizeHintEv). (I didn't know this until now either... not sure why they chose to do it this way.)

So looks like you'll have to re-implement `QScrollArea` or find a different display strategy.  To re-implement we just basically need to re-write the `sizeHint()` function but w/out the silly constraint.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>

class ScrollArea : public QScrollArea
{
  public:
    ScrollArea(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QScrollArea(parent) {}

    QSize sizeHint() const
    {
      QSize sz = QScrollArea::viewportSizeHint();
      const int f = frameWidth() * 2;
      sz += QSize(f, f);
      if (verticalScrollBarPolicy() == Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        sz.setWidth(sz.width() + verticalScrollBar()->sizeHint().width());
      if (horizontalScrollBarPolicy() == Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        sz.setHeight(sz.height() + horizontalScrollBar()->sizeHint().height());
      return sz;
    }
};

class Dialog : public QDialog {
  public:
    Dialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QDialog(parent) {
      auto dialogLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
      auto scrollArea = new ScrollArea(this);
      //scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);
      auto scrollWidget = new QWidget(this);
      auto scrollLayout = new QVBoxLayout(scrollWidget);
      auto button = new QPushButton("Button", this);
      button->setFixedSize(600, 30);

      scrollLayout->addWidget(button);
      scrollArea->setWidget(scrollWidget);
      dialogLayout->addWidget(scrollArea);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  return Dialog().exec();
}
```

As a small aside, if you add the items to the scroll area in the order I show here, you do not technically need the `setWidgetResizable(true)` bit which I commented out (I noticed that in the original order you had it in, the inner widget wasn't being shown properly sized).

ADDED: The reason `sizeHint()` matters is because that's what `QDialog` uses to determine it's initial size. One could also (for example) re-implement `QDialog::showEvent()` and set a specific size for the dialog there based on whatever criteria make sense.

Comment: Thank you very much!
About 2px padding: maybe we need to add `QSize(2 * frameWidth(), 2 * frameWidth())` to sz, as in the beggining of original `sizeHint()` implementation?
About `setWidgetResizable()`: it is required if something will be added to `scrollLayout` after `scrollWidget` is set in my case

Comment: @Kot, you're welcome, and yes, you're absolutely right, adding `frameWidth() * 2` works w/out needing the extra padding. I edited the code in my answer.

Comment: There's a mistake in your code, that I noticed just now. in `SizeHint` you're checking presense of `horizontalScrollBar`, but adding `verticalScrollBar`'s height and vice versa